# using map function to convert state to region in new datafram column. all rows showing up as NaN. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5S5E.png)reading in csv file, cleaning it, and filling all null values with 0.

```
    import pandas as pd
    broccoli = pd.read_csv('broccoli.csv')
    region = {
    'Alabama': 'S',
    'Montana': 'W',
    'Alaska': 'W',
    'Nebraska': 'MW',
    'Arizona': 'W',
    'Nevada': 'W',
    'Arkansas': 'S',
    'New Hampshire': 'NE',
    'California': 'W',
    'New Jersey': 'NE',
    'Colorado': 'W',
    'New Mexico': 'W',
    'Connecticut': 'NE',
    'New York': 'NE',
    'Delaware': 'S',
    'North Carolina': 'S',
    'Florida': 'S',
    'North Dakota': 'MW',
    'Georgia': 'S',
    'Ohio': 'MW',
    'Hawaii': 'W',
    'Oklahoma': 'S',
    'Idaho': 'W',
    'Oregon': 'W',
    'Illinois': 'MW',
    'Pennsylvania': 'NE',
    'Indiana': 'MW',
    'Rhode Island': 'NE',
    'Iowa': 'MW',
    'South Carolina': 'S',
    'Kansas': 'MW',
    'South Dakota': 'MW',
    'Kentucky': 'S',
    'Tennessee': 'S',
    'Louisiana': 'S',
    'Texas': 'S',
    'Maine': 'NE',
    'Utah': 'W',
    'Maryland': 'S',
    'Vermont': 'NE',
    'Massachusetts': 'NE',
    'Virginia': 'S',
    'Michigan': 'MW',
    'Washington': 'W',
    'Minnesota': 'MW',
    'West Virginia': 'S',
    'Mississippi': 'S',
    'Wisconsin': 'MW',
    'Missouri': 'MW',
    'Wyoming': 'W',
   } 
   df_broccoli['Region'] = df_broccoli['State'].map(region) 
   df_broccoli
```

I'm getting NaN still for all rows in the column. The data frame is cleaned and all the columns line up correctly. I've been unable to fix this. please help if you can.

Comment: Can show show us a couple of lines of what's in broccoli.csv?

Comment: link to image of the dataframe at the top